# Get AuthenticodeSignatureInformation of file

Tags: c#, .net, security, cryptography, digital-signature

The only example I've found for using [AuthenticodeSignatureInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.authenticodesignatureinformation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)   gets the instance from a [ManifestSignatureInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.manifestsignatureinformation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  . and the only way I've found to get *that* is using one of its [VerifySignature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341511%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)   methods. And all of *those* need an [ActivationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  which in turn:

> Identifies the activation context for the **current application**.

(emphasis added.)

**So**

How do I get the `AuthenticodeSignatureInformation` of a ***file***? (I'm aware of alternative ways to deal with Authenticode signatures. I'm looking specifically for this class.)